# MDX query to except specific date from date range

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I am need to delete all 2 month from set. This code return all date range without excepting 2 month.

```
SELECT 
   {[Measures].[In]} ON COLUMNS,
   EXCEPT([Date].[2014].[1] : [Date].[2016].[2], [Date].[Month].[2]) ON ROWS
FROM [Shop hourly]
```

Print screen for whytheq
[image]

My decision based on whytheq answear. I create a dimension for all kind of dates, and except them. Example:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[In sum]} ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
        {[Shop].[11], [Shop].[22], [Shop].[33]} * 
        Except([Quarter].Children, [Quarter].[2]) * 
        [Month].Children ON ROWS
FROM [Shop hourly]
WHERE 
    ([Date].[2013].[1].[1] : [Date].[2016].[1].[1]) * 
    Except([Year].Children, [Year].[2014])
```

[image]

Comment: so you want to delete {February 2014, February 2015, February 2016} ?

Comment: Yes it is what i want

Comment: - I answered the question below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AdventureWorks` I can do the following:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Except
    (
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2005]&[7]
      : 
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[7]
     ,Exists
      (
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
       ,[Date].[Calendar Quarter of Year].&[CY Q3]
      )
    ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

So adapting the above to your cube maybe looks like the following:

```
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[In]} ON COLUMNS
 ,Except
  (
    [Date].[2014].[1] : [Date].[2016].[2]
   ,Exists
    (
      [Date].MEMBERS
     ,[Date].[Month].[2]
    )
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Shop hourly];
```

Comment: Mondrian change [Date].[Month].[2] to [Date].[2012].[2] I dont know why it is doing it.

Comment: you will need to add a screenprint of the structure of your `[Date]` dimension for me to have an idea of what is happening.

Comment: I create a Year, Month, Day dimension and except from them. It works :-)

Comment: @Nodon great glad you got something working. Could you add a second screenprint so future users can see what they need in place for this answer to work?